# How to get access to an http-only cookie using Meteor

Tags: cookies, meteor

**Some background:**

- **my site**: *site.domain.com*
- http-only cookie set by domain.com.
- I can see the cookie in the resources view in **Chrome** & in the network traffic

I really need read access to an **http-only** (domain) cookie from either meteor client or server (doesnt matter to me)

http-only renders any technique that uses **"document.cookie"** useless unfortunately.

I can see the cookie details being passed back to Meteor inside the various **sockjs GET** requests, what i probably need is a way to get at that raw request info so i can tease out the cookie value.

Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at trying to access the headers via req or using connect's cookieparser:

**Server Js**

```
__meteor_bootstrap__.app.use(connect.cookieParser()).use(function(req, res, next) {
    Fiber(function () {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req.cookies));
    }).run();
});
```

Have a look at : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/meteor-talk/xLGOcruZ4c4 for more info about this